# save data in NSManagedObjects while using setPropertiesToFetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

How to save data in `NSManagedObjects` while using `setPropertiesToFetch`. I am using `setPropertiesToFetch` but the data which is saving is in dictionary format. I want that data in `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: go through this http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started  completed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSManagedObject is supporting Key-Value Coding, so you can use `setValue:forKey:`  method.